# Escaping of hex values in string literals

Tags: string, go, escaping, hex

I am attempting to escape a specific hex value in a golang string. The function call looks something like this:

```
Insert(0, "\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\b\x03")
Insert(25, "\x00\x00\x00\x06PLTE")
Insert(43, "\x00\x00\x00\x02tRNS")
Insert(57, "\x00\x00\t;IDATx\xDA\x010\t\xCF\xF6") // problem line
Insert(2432, "\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND")
```

The problem arises when the language interprets the "\xDA" hex escape. Instead of correctly escaping to a Ú value, it is escaped to � (the Replacement Character).

I ensured this is what was occuring in the following playground example:

```
fmt.Println("\xDA")
i := 218
h := fmt.Sprintf("%x", i)
fmt.Printf("Hex conf of '%d' is '%s'\n", i, h)  
fmt.Println(string(i))
```

This snippet, when run, prints

```
�
Hex conf of '218' is 'da'
Ú
```

Am I missing something here? The fact that "\xDA" is being escaped to a value of 65533 is throwing off my entire program, which relies on the CRC32 and some other checksums. This does not occur in the [javascript version](https://github.com/JohnDDuncanIII/messagefaces/blob/master/chrome/content/lib/xface.js) of this program (which itself is a translation from James compface program, written in C).

Here is the playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/c-XMK68maX

Comment: `\xDA` _is_ a valid hex escape. The utf8 encoding of `rune(218)` is `\xc3\x9a`. I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen here.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I was expecting `fmt.Println("\xDA")` to output 'Ú' instead of '�'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go strings are just a series of bytes, but when an encoding is needed, it's assumed to be utf8. The value `\xda` isn't a valid utf8 character, so when printing it's converted to the `unicode.ReplacementCharacter` "�"

```
    ReplacementChar = '\uFFFD'     // Represents invalid code points.
```

If you want the rune value of `\xda` in a string literal, use a unicode escape: `\u00DA`, or use the utf8 encoded: `\xc3\x9a`, or use the character itself: `Ú`.

https://play.golang.org/p/EJZIqCI_Gr

If you actually want a single byte value of `\xda` in your string, that is what you have and the printed character is inconsequential.

Comment: Thanks! I just ended up changing the hex value to unicode (a couple minutes after the post) and everything went smoothly from there ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your input looks like ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1). Convert it to UTF-8. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

// ISO88591ToString maps ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) to string (UTF-8).
func ISO88591ToString(iso string) string {
    var utf []rune
    for i := 0; i < len(iso); i++ {
        r := iso[i]
        if utf == nil {
            if r < utf8.RuneSelf {
                continue
            }
            utf = make([]rune, len(iso))
            for j, r := range iso[:i] {
                utf[j] = rune(r)
            }
        }
        utf[i] = rune(r)
    }
    if utf == nil {
        return string(iso)
    }
    return string(utf)
}

func main() {
    l1 := "\x00\x00\t;IDATx\xDA\x010\t\xCF\xF6"
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", l1)
    s := ISO88591ToString(l1)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
}
```

Output:

```
"\x00\x00\t;IDATx\xda\x010\t\xcf\xf6"
"\x00\x00\t;IDATxÚ\x010\tÏö"
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Go are UTF-8, and `\xDA` isn't a valid UTF-8 sequence by itself, meaning printing it as a part of a string will yield the Unicode replacement character U+FFFD instead of what you wanted (Ú, or U+00DA).

You seem to be working with raw bytes, however, so you should consider whether you want the rune represented by `\u00DA`, which is encoded in UTF-8 as the 2-byte sequence `\xC3\x8F`, or whether you require the single byte `\xDA`. The former will print Ú as you want with the caveat that it requires 2 bytes. The latter will not print as you expect, yet it will correctly be interpret `\xDA` as 1 byte rather than 2 bytes.

Here's an illustrative example you can [run on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fHRm6Urqns):

```
func main() {
    // A string made up of UTF-8 lead bytes.
    dataString := "\xCF\xDA\xF6"

    // Doesn't print what you think it should.
    for _, c := range dataString {
        fmt.Printf("%X ", c)
    }
    fmt.Println()

    // Convert the string's bytes to a byte slice.
    data := []byte(dataString)

    // Now it should print CF, DA, F6.
    for _, b := range data {
        fmt.Printf("%X ", b)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```